# Integrate Facebook sql table

Tags: php, facebook

I have a table set in my current website

```
users

id
username
password
email
```

If I were to integrate Facebook authentication on my website, What would I store in the database to recognise which user the row in the database has the Facebook? Is is the userid of the Facebook owner or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well pal go [here to see the official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

[and here is a tutorial i used some time ago it is really covers all the angles](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)